# Bitmap functions in Adobe ExtendScript

Tags: bitmap, extendscript

I want to get bitmap data from a loaded bitmap in Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit.
Does ExtendScript have built-in functions for this? Or do I need to write them myself?
Let's say png or bmp.

Comment: Some context would help - which Adobe application are you writing the script for?  Are you trying to load the bitmap from a file, or from a document in the application?

Answer (score 0):

you can write them for Photoshop. you use the color sample method. you could then loop through the pixels and store them in an array/matrix and do whatever it is you want, even export to CSV.